# Does Qt Extended Support

Tags: user-interface, qt, embedded-linux

I am evaluating Embedded Linux GUI toolkits for an upcoming project and have put together a must have “feature list” to help me with the decision:

1. Color gradients in graphics (for menu headers buttons, icons, etc…)
2. The ability to draw complex wave graphics with say a background grid, notations.
3. The ability to swap between to landscape and portrait orientation.

Qt Extended seems to be a popular toolkit with a wide user base. Can anyone tell me if the above features are available in Qt Extended? Any links to tutorials or documentation would be great!

Comment: You are really asking about Qt, not Qt Extended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, either through a [custom style](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstyle.html), a [style sheet](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/stylesheet.html) or by implementing custom widgets (depending on how exotic you want to get)
2. Sure, you can draw anything. For what you're after, check out [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/).
3. Yes, but you might have to apply some magic of your own here. The [screen driver](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt-embedded-displaymanagement.html) does support this, so it can be done. Also, the Qt for Symbian port does this on the fly, so looking at their solution and then applying it to your scenario might work.